# How can I observe beingPresented, beingDismissed properties of UIViewController Object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate, key-value-observing

I want to know how I can get to know when a viewController appears, disappears from the main window from the UIApplication. I don't want to put code in each and every UIViewController, but observe lifecycle of each viewcontroller from the UIApplication.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

Every view controller has a life cycle. So every view controller has separate life cycle method. So you have to put code each and every UIViewController. In app delegate we check the application state. 
The state's are:

1. Active state
2. Inactive state
3. Background state
4. Not Running state
5. Suspended state

Delegate Method:

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationWillTerminate:
```

View Controller Life cycle method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I was not clear. I want to monitor lifecycle of each viewcontroller from appdelegate.

Comment: @AditGoel How can you do this ?

Comment: That is exactly my question